# Ajax não funciona no android

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, formulário, mobile

Estou fazendo uma requisição ajax que funciona perfeitamente no Desktop, porém quando vou testar no android não funciona, se alguém puder me ajudar

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#loginform").on('submit', function() {
            var input_data = $('#loginform').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php','login_post'); ?>",
                data: input_data,
                success: function(msg) {
                    var reg1 = /login_error/g;
                    if (reg1.test(msg)) {
                         $('#message').html("Usuário ou senha incorretos.");
                    }else {
                        // login success. redirect users to some page.
                        //$(location).attr('href', '/my-account/');
                        //or reload the same page
                        if($('#user_pass').val() != '' && $('#user_login').val() != '') {
                          location.reload();
                        } else {
                          $('#message').html("Usuário ou senha não preenchidos!");
                          $('#message').fadeIn();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: No navegador ou em um `WebView`?

Comment: No navegador, Google Chrome Android 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o jQuery mobile para o seu projeto. Ele permite que você utilize comandos jQuery para todos os dispositivos móveis, tanto ios quanto android. Após inserido no projeto é só utilizar o jQuery do jeito que você já está acostumado.

Obs: Verifique qual a versão do jQuery usado no seu projeto, para que você baixe uma versão compatível do jQuery mobile.

Link: https://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Inseri o jquery mobile e nada...
o link é esse https://sbacv-go.com.br/minha-conta/
e o erro é no google chrome do android 5.1, no iphone e em versões mais recentes do android funciona normalmente

Comment: Sabe qual o erro? Você tentar fazer um debug pelo chrome no seu navegador pareado com seu celular pelo link chrome://inspect/#devices no seu chrome

Comment: tento exibir o erro e não exibe, só sei que da erro porque adicionei no ajax o evento error e mandei dar um alert ai ele cai no alert do erro sendo que no Desktop e nos outros dispositivos cai no alert do success, estou pensando em ignorar pelo fato de que vários outros dispositivos não apresentaram erro, somente no Moto G

Comment: Tente fazer um debug remoto do erro como explica esse link https://tableless.com.br/debug-remoto-com-chrome-android/ .Com o erro em mãos, talvez seja mais fácil de resolver.